# failed to understand some js object behavior

Tags: object, methods, state, javascript-objects

```js
console.log("hello");

var data = {
    data() {
        return { count: 0 };
    },
    plus() {
        return ++this.data().count;
    },
};

console.log(data.data().count); //0
console.log(data.plus()); //1
console.log(data.data().count); //0
```

Why can't I mutate the count?

It only increments when I use the plus method, but the core state of the count does not increment, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're only incrementing or returning a local variable. So a new object `{ count: 0 }` will be created every time you call `data()`.

So e.g. if you call `plus()` more than once, you'll also receive incorrect answers:

```js
console.log("hello");

var data = {
    data() {
        return { count: 0 };
    },
    plus() {
        return ++this.data().count;
    },
};

console.log(data.plus()); // 1
console.log(data.plus()); // 1 => not 2
console.log(data.plus()); // 1 => not 3
```

In order for the change to "persist" you need to add `count` as a member of the object i. e. make the same instance of counter available for both the `data()` as well as the `plus()` function and then manipulate this shared instance in both of the functions.

```js
console.log("hello");

var data = {
    count: 0,
    data() {
        return this.count;
    },
    plus() {
        return ++this.count;
    },
};

console.log(data.data()); // 0
console.log(data.plus()); // 1
console.log(data.data()); // 1
console.log(data.plus()); // 2
```

> Alternatively if you don't want to actually add `counter` to the object you could also use a global variable `let counter = 0`. It's just important to make sure you edit the same instance of counter in both functions.